# How to identify which "relationship" is being followed by a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have the situation illustrated in this picture.

[image: The storyboard]

In a nutshell, I have a single view controller that can be configured in different ways, and I'd like to be able to specify these ways via IB. I thought that those two arrows were segues, so I figured I'd override `prepareForSegue:sender:`, and configure the destination view controllers according to each segue's id. I only need to do this once, at initialisation time, so I figured the approach would work. However, those two arrows turned out not to be segues -- or at least `prepareForSegue:sender:` doesn't fire for them.

Can something like this be done at all? Worst case scenario, I can do this programmatically, no big deal, but I figured storyboards are cool, so why not use them?

Comment: `prepareForSegue` should fire for the embed segues, but you will need to have a custom uitabbarcontroller class to do access it. You should be able to use user defined runtime properties in IB https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/AddUserDefinedRuntimeAttributes.html

Comment: I thought it was a nice idea, but unfortunately the class has to be key value coding-compliant for you to be able to set runtime attributes like that. Since I'd attach the attribute to the tabBarItem, there is no chance of doing that unless I make my own. I could use tags.

Comment: @Morpheu5 Did you see my answer? It is sooo easy (unless I misunderstood your question). In fact, I did it just today.

Comment: @RobertVaessen I tried that but I found that the tabBarItems of each view controller were not initialized at the time viewDidLoad ran on the tab bar view controller.

Comment: @Morpheu5 Oops, I missed that you want to do the initialization in the TabBarController. I have updated my answer. And, because my answer is simple, I suspect that I might still be missing something about your situation :-(

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController is a container view controller in which the contained view controllers are initialized shortly after its own initialization. An analogy can be drawn to UINavigationController and it's rootViewController. Even though in Storyboards it appears there's a segue between the container view controller and its view controllers those view controllers were created at initialization and are presented on screen at the same time as the container view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Those arrows are relationships, not segues.

In the viewDidLoad method of your Table View Controllers you can distinguish them by their Tab Bar Items.

If you want to do the initialization from the viewDidLoad method of the TabBarController then:

```
// If restoration IDs were assigned in the Storyboard ....
func initializeChildren(tabBar: UITabBarController) {
    if let children = tabBar.viewControllers {
        for child in children {
            let table = child as! UITableViewController
            switch table.restorationIdentifier! {
                case "Tabel 1":
                    table.title = "Cats Table"
                    break
                case "Table 2":
                    table.title = "Dogs Table"
                    break
                default:
                    print("Unknown child!!!")
                    break
            }
        }
    }
}

// If it is okay to "know" the tab order
func initializeChildren(tabBar: UITabBarController) {
    if let children = tabBar.viewControllers {
        for var i = 0; i < children.count; ++i {
            let table = children[i] as! UITableViewController
            switch  i {
                case 0:
                    table.title = "Cats Table"
                    break
                 case 1:
                     table.title = "Dogs Table"
                     break
                 default:
                     print("Unknown child!!!")
                     break
            }
        }
    }
}
```